# How to distinguish link click vs transitionTo

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to remember the scroll position of a page using that code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(angularEvent, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
    $rootScope.scrollPosCache['dailyController'] = $window.pageYOffset;
});
```

When the page infinitely-scrolls I am using `ui-router's` `transitionTo` to modify the current url in the browser history like that:

```
$state.transitionTo('daily', { page: pageIndex }, { notify: false, location: 'replace' });
```

the transition changes the search string to e.g.: http://example.com/?page=1/2/3/4/etc

so, the `$locationChangeStart` code is running both when I make the transition and when the user leaves the list page to follow a link to a detail page.

How do I know the location change has come from a transition and not from a click through? (I only want to remember the scroll position when the page is left)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `$stateChangeStart` and not `$locationChangeStart`.